# How can we explain that glucose at its concentration less than a Km for the transporter enters the peripheral circulation?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, glucose

I'm studying biochemistry from Kaplan's book. In it, I found the following paragraph in the topic on glucose metabolism:
"GLUT 2, a low-affinity transporter, is in hepatocytes. After a meal,
portal blood from the intestine is rich in glucose. GLUT 2 captures the
excess glucose primarily for storage. When the glucose concentration
drops below the Km for the transporter, much of the remainder leaves
the liver and enters the peripheral circulation."

A similar question has already been here, but it didn't help me find an understanding of this. How can we explain that glucose at its concentration less than a Km for the transporter enters the peripheral circulation? Why is this related to Km? I understand, that at glucose concentration equal to a Km, V will be equal to half V max. But even at a low concentration, glucose will still bind to the transporter, although not so actively. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that transporting glucose into the hepatocytes at a low speed will be energetically unprofitable or because of the speed of blood flow, it will no longer have time to get into the hepatocytes. Please, give your opinion

Comment: I correct you as invited because you are wrong. Please read the sections about enzyme kinetics in your text very carefully. You will find nothing about energetically or “speed” and certainly blood flow is irrelevant as the next unit of blood has the same concentration as the preceding one.

Comment: @David Ok, thank you very much